# javascript equivalent for oracle date TRUNC function

Tags: javascript, oracle, date

i'm searching for a way to replicate oracle TRUNC date function in javascript

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php

basically its rounding a unix timestamp last interval (round time 11pm to 4hrs will result in 8pm)

my first attempt was:

`const trunc = (ts,candleSize) => (Math.floor((ts)/(candleSize)) * candleSize)`

but this worked for intervals up to 1hr only.

example: `trunc(Date('2021-01-01T13:17:00'), 5*60) === Date('2021-01-01T13:15:00')`

but `trunc(Date('2021-01-01T13:16:00'), 60*60*4) !== Date('2021-01-01T12:00:00')`

so i tried using modulo:

`const trunc = (ts,candleSize) => (ts - (ts % candleSize)`

and it worked fine for most intervals
example:
``

but still i was not able to do things like (Quarter) or (first day of month) or first day of week

Comment: You may use `Date.prototype.get*` and `Date.prototype.set*` methods and operate on date parts. The only issue is a week, which cannot be so easily calculated.

Comment: I'd have thought that rounding 11 pm (23:00) to 4 hour increments would be 24:00 or 00:00. Reducing to 8 pm (20:00) is more like flooring.

Comment: Calling *Date* as a function as in `Date('2021-01-01T13:17:00')` just returns a string for the current date and time, it doesn't take any arguments. Did you accidentally omit the *new* operator when posting?

Comment: There is no single algorithm to determine the start of a year, month, week, day, hour, etc. You need different algorithms depending on the unit you want the start of, especially for quarter (day? year? calendar, financial, budget?). Even the start of the week is different for different cultures. `ts - (ts % candleSize)` will only work for UTC or where the host offset is in integer multiple of *candleSize*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how Oracle's TRUNC works, but here's something that might suit. It will truncate (floor) to any multiple of the specified unit, e.g. start of century is "year*100", start of quarter is "month*3", etc. A missing multiple is 1, so "month" is equivalent to "month*1".

```js
/* Truncate date to previous full unit, does not
 * modify passed date.
 * Start of week is Monday.
 *
 * @param {Date} date - date to truncate
 * @param {string} unit - one of: year, month, week,
 *                        day, hour, minute, second
 *                        optional subunit separated by *
 *                        hour*12 = trunc to nearest whole multiple of 12 hours
 *                        minute*10 = trunc to nearest whole multiple of 10 minutes
 *
 * @returns {Date} truncated Date
*/
function trunc(date = new Date(), unit = 'day') {
  let d = new Date(+date);
  
  // Parse unit & subunit
  unit = unit.toLowerCase();
  let [u, uSub] = unit.split('*');
  
  // Deal with invalid or missing sub unit
  if (!Number.isInteger(+uSub)) uSub = 1;
  
  // Truncating functions
  let f = {
    year:        d => [d.getFullYear() - d.getFullYear() % uSub, 0],
    month:       d => [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() - d.getMonth() % uSub],
    // Start of week is Monday
    week:        d => [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() - d.getDay() + 1],
    day:         d => [d.setHours(0,0,0,0)],
    hour:        d => [d.setHours(d.getHours() - d.getHours() % uSub, 0,0,0)],
    minute:      d => [d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getMinutes() % uSub, 0,0)],
    second:      d => [d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() - d.getSeconds() % uSub)],
    millisecond: d => [d.setMilliseconds(d.getMilliseconds() - d.getMilliseconds() % uSub)]
  };
  
  // Validate unit & call appropriate function
  if (f.hasOwnProperty(u)) {
    return new Date(...f[u](d));
  }
  // If invalid unit, return undefined
}

// Examples
let d = new Date(2019, 11, 15, 23, 59, 41, 55);
console.log('Test date => ' + d.toString());
'year*100 year*10 year month*3 month week day hour*12 hour*6 hour*4 hour*3 hour*2 hour minute*30 minute*20 minute*15 minute*10 minute*5 minute second*30 second'.split(' ')
  .forEach(
    unit => console.log(`${unit} => ${trunc(d, unit).toString()}`)
  );
  
// Default (start of today)
console.log(`Default => ${trunc().toString()}`)
```